# How to scale imageview image to specific size?

Tags: android, imageview, scale, setbounds

I created an imageview image, but I want to scale it to be no greater than a fifth of the width and a sixth of the height of the android device's screen size.

Here I get the width and height of the screen:

```
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    int width = metrics.widthPixels;
    int height = metrics.heightPixels;
```

here I create my imageview:

```
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setImageResource(icons[0]);
```

and here I try to scale my imageview:

```
    imageView.getDrawable().setBounds(0, 0, width/5, height/6);
```

This last part is the stickler. After typing this in I get no errors and my program runs normally - but the image is not scaled. Basically that last line of code seems to have no effect and I have no idea why, any pointers?

Rest of my code:

```
    imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);

    int mh = imageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();
    int mw = imageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();

    imageView.setX(width/2 - Math.round(width/5));
    imageView.setY(height/2 - Math.round(height/6) - mActionBarSize);

    relativeLayout.addView(imageView);
    setContentView(relativeLayout);
```

Answer (score 1):

do this :

```
imageView.getLayoutParams().height = (int) Math.round(height/6);
imageView.getLayoutParams().width = (int) Math.round(width/5);
imageView.requestLayout();  // If you're setting the height/width after the layout has already been 'laid out'
```

see this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestLayout%28%29) to learn more about requestLayout():

*Call this when something has changed which has invalidated the layout of this view. This will schedule a layout pass of the view tree.*

But ususally the view is calling it automatically, you don't have to care about that... (So for me I use it to force the view to do what I want to do)

Comment: Could you explain that last part? For instance why did you use "image_view" instead of imageView? And what does that last part do exactly?

Comment: i was wrong in using "image_view" , I have just updated in my answer.
I added some informations about View.requestLayout()

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pageImage);
    imgView.getLayoutParams().height = 100;
    imgView.getLayoutParams().width = 100;
```

Comment: my program crashes when I try running this,  here is my code:
 
imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        imageView.getLayoutParams().height = (int) Math.round(height/6);
        imageView.getLayoutParams().width = (int) Math.round(width/5);
        imageView.requestLayout();     
        int mh = imageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();
        int mw = imageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
        imageView.setX(width/2 - mw/2);
        imageView.setY(height/2 - mh/2 - mActionBarSize);
        relativeLayout.addView(imageView);
        setContentView(relativeLayout);